# TransactionalCacheManager and how to get TransactionalCache and clear

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

It is possible to take the specific TransactionalCache per transaction and invoke clear? I'm working with spring context but seems that the transactional cache manager is out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible now (the current version is 3.4.6).

`TransactionalCache` is a private field of the `TransactionCacheManager` which is in turn a private field of the [`CachingExecutor`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/executor/CachingExecutor.java).

The cache is only cleared during queries and updates when mapper configuration (`flushCache` attribute and query type) instructs mybatis to do so.